# How browser extenstion will works and communicate with website?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, firefox-addon

I am new to asp.net and learning various things. I want to make browser(For Fire Fox only) extension that will interact with asp.net website.

Purpose of this extension is to send data from client side to server side without opening website and save this data to database under user profile

Any help, self learning resources, Books on extension will be appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Install addon-sdk from here and then see `pageMod`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Installation
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod